# Issue with javascript splice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to remove an index from an array and I used javascript `splice` to implement that. But something weird is happening.

```
var dataarray = [{"childid":"1275","id":"5501"},
                    {"childid":"1276","id":"5501"},
                    {"childid":"1277","id":"5502"},
                    {"childid":"1278","id":"5502"},
                    {"childid":"1279","id":"5501"}
                    ,{"childid":"1280","id":"5501"}];
var temp_dataarray = dataarray;

$.each(dataarray, function(i, data) {
    if(data.id != 1275)
    {
        temp_dataarray.splice(i, 1);
        console.log(' Dataarray count : '+dataarray.length);
        console.log(' Temp count : '+temp_dataarray.length);
    }

});
```

**console.log output**

```
 Dataarray count : 5   
 Temp count : 5   
 Dataarray count : 4      
 Temp count : 4   
 Dataarray count : 3   
 Temp count : 3   
 TypeError: data is undefined
```

In my code I am not altering the `dataarray` but its count gets decreasing. Why is it happening like that?

Comment: `I was trying to remove an index froma jason ... ` Jason.. really?

Comment: That's not JSON. If it's in JavaScript code, it's never JSON, unless it's inside a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You **are** altering the `dataarray` array.

Just assigning an object (including arrays) to a variable doesn't do a copy. The value of a non primitive variable is a reference to the value. Here, the two variables hold the same reference. `dataarray` and `temp_dataarray` are the same array.

The solution here is to clone the array.

Replace

```
var temp_dataarray = dataarray;
```

to

```
var temp_dataarray = dataarray.slice();
```

But note that there are simpler solutions to filter an array:

```
var dataarray = [{"childid":"1275","id":"5501"},
                    {"childid":"1276","id":"5501"},
                    {"childid":"1277","id":"5502"},
                    {"childid":"1278","id":"5502"},
                    {"childid":"1279","id":"5501"}
                    ,{"childid":"1280","id":"5501"}];

var temp_dataarray = dataarray.filter(function(data){
     return data.id == 1275
});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/motuvubalu/1/edit?js,console,output)

Side note: It looks from your data as if you'd want to use `data.childid` instead of `data.id` in the filter.

Comment: You're obviously correct, but I think it would help readers understand if you took the chance to explain about references & deep copies.

Comment: @Amit I'm trying to make it clearer. Does that look good now ?